# problem with Create Dblclick event at vb6 ListView

Tags: vb6

If one of the items in the list view is double-clicked,

I need to open a other form(psa33), looking for the column value of the double-clicked product.

The column value for that double-clicked item must appear entered in the newly opened form.

How can I make it?

help me plz

```
Private Sub ListView1_DblClick()
   PSA33.Show
End Sub
```

now it works only form change but i need to do more.

i think i need to find listview1' s doubleclicked item's column data

and send it to psa33

but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Have a look at the Treeview's [`.HitTest` event](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_treeview_popup.html).

Comment: Add a property to your PSA33 form where you will assign the value just before you show the form.  Then inside the form you can do whatever you need, like assigning the value to a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

The property `ListView1.SelectedItem` holds a reference to the selected ListItem.

Be sure to check if the property is pointing to a valid item because the user could also make a double click in the empty space of a ListView.

Example code:

```
    If ListView1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No tem selected", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Can't proceed"
    Else
        PSA33.<NewPropertyYouHaveToCreate> = ListView2.SelectedItem.Text
        PSA33.Show
    End If
```